# How to overapproximate the intersection of zonotope with a halfspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

I have a zonotope $Z$ in $\mathbb{R}^d $ given by:

$Z=\lbrace x | x=\epsilon_1g_1+...+\epsilon_ng_n+c \rbrace$

where $c,g_1,...,g_n$ are the bias and the generators of $Z$ and $\epsilon_i\in[-1,1]$.

I am interested in the intersection of Z with the halfspace given by $x\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\...\\0\end{pmatrix}$ (positive first value).

This intersection is not a zonotope, but I need my result to be a zonotope, so instead I am looking for an overapproximation of the intersection.

I have already found an algothim to get this result: for each generator, I find how much I can change the bounds of its corresponding $\epsilon$ and not change any vertex in the positive halfspace. After changing the bounds, its not difficult to find an identical zonotope with bounds between -1 and 1 by changing the generator size and the bias.

However, this algorithm is linear in the number of vertices, which can be exponential in the  number of dimensions, and becomes impractical even with as little as 10 dimensions. Is there a more efficient method?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that just picking Z itself as the overapproximation is not good enough? Which fraction of Z do you expect to be within the half-space? What do you need this overapproximation for?

Comment: I am using the overapproximation for neural network verification using abstract interpretation (basically I'm starting with a bound on the neuron values and then apply ReLu, that's where the x>=0 comes from).
Z is arbitrary so I don't have any information on how much of it is in the halfspace.
Picking Z itself is not good enough, that is correct. Its especially frustrating since I already found a solution that gives a very tight approximation, and its only using a single vertex (the "rightmost" that is negative), but finding this vertex requires iterating over all of them...

Comment: @Magma, tagging because I didn't tag in my previous comment

Comment: As an example, what kind of solution are you looking for in case the zonotope is a cube $[-1,1]^n$ and the half-space is given by $x_1 + \ldots + x_n \geq 0$?

Comment: In that case the ideal overapproximation is actually the original hypercube, so I would expect to get exactly that.